# JSON response was so late

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I have url like this:

example.com/account/reset/6b183b5025d5b865963f4499f257705d

and i have a ajax submit in my script like this:

```
form.ajaxSubmit({
                url: '/account/reset',
                success: function (result, status, xhr, $form) {
                    if (result.status === 'success') {
                        window.location.replace("/account/login");
                    }else{
                        btn.removeClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', false);
                        showErrorMsg(form, 'danger', result.message);
                        alert(result.status);
                    }
                }
            });
```

here's the response:

```
{"status":"success","title":"Success!","message":"Password changed successfully please login to continue"}
```

when the form ajax was submitted, i got a response which trigger an alert with 'undefined' and after that alert i got the json response with success status. how come i got 2 response? and how do i can caught that second response before the first one?

here's the full JS if needed:

```
//== Class Definition
let reset = function () {

    let reset = $('#m_login');

    let showErrorMsg = function (form, type, msg) {
        let alert = $('<div class="m-alert m-alert--outline alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissible" role="alert">\
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>\
            <span></span>\
        </div>');

        form.find('.alert').remove();
        alert.prependTo(form);
        //alert.animateClass('fadeIn animated');
        mUtil.animateClass(alert[0], 'fadeIn animated');
        alert.find('span').html(msg);
    };

    let resetPassword = function () {
        $('#m_login_reset_submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let btn = $(this);
            let form = $(this).closest('form');

            form.validate({
                rules: {
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 12
                    },
                    password_confirmation: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: '#password'
                    }
                }
            });

            if (!form.valid()) {
                return;
            }

            btn.addClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', true);

            form.ajaxSubmit({
                url: '/account/reset',
                success: function (result, status, xhr, $form) {
                    if (result.status === 'success') {
                        window.location.replace("/account/login");
                    }else{
                        btn.removeClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', false);
                        showErrorMsg(form, 'danger', result.message);
                        alert(result.status);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };


    //== Public Functions
    return {
        // public functions
        init: function () {
            resetPassword();
        }
    };
}();
//== Class Initialization
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    reset.init();
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opt, thrownError) {
        swal({
            title: xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText,
            //text: "Error requesting : " + opt.url +" "+ thrownError,
            text: xhr.responseText,
            type: "error",
            timer: 15000
        });
        $('#m_login_signin_submit').removeClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: What does `showErrorMsg` do? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: it just to show an error when it happen with a message. i can remove and it will change nothing.

Comment: I think that you get the data as a string instead of JSON. Try parsing the JSON first. If there was a second alert, there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: {"status":"success","title":"Success!","message":"Password changed successfully please login to continue"}

i use PHP json_encode. and it give me that above result.

Comment: first, PHP encodes the data to a string as JSON. The javascript side needs to undo that.

Comment: my data is not a string, it's an array:

Comment: $response = [
                            'status' => 'success',
                            'title' => 'Success!',
                            'message' => 'Password changed successfully please login to continue'
                        ];
                        echo json_encode($response);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174527/discussion-between-niedzejkob-and-ying).

Comment: @NieDzejkob you right, u can write your answer if you want to so i can select it. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you've seen two alert windows, or even if that's the case, since you've described it a little ambigously. However, the reason you're getting `undefined` is that JavaScript won't decode the JSON data automatically. Therefore, you need to decode the JSON to a data structure first:

```
success: function (encoded, status, xhr, $form) {
    decoded = JSON.parse(encoded)
    if (decoded.status === 'success') {
```